# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC Identity does not appear to be getting the default Layout

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a layout for a portal that worked fine in .NET Core 3.1 and 5.  I am splitting my portal into two apps: one for participants and one for our faculty and staff (you know, separation of concerns and to keep the application from getting humongous. Participants hardly share any functionality with faculty and staff).

Anyway, I cannot, for the life of me, get my default layout to render in my Identity pages.

This is how they are showing:

[image: ![enter image description here]

This is how it should render:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I do have my `_ViewStart.cshtml` that is located in `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` pointing to the correct place:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";
}
```

I do not know what is going on. This has never been an issue before.  It appears as if it is not getting any layout files whatsoever.

Am I missing a step? Is there someone I tell it to make sure it has access to the files?

I have searched the web. I found this on StackOverflow [Layout not working on asp.net core 3.0 for user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58651929/layout-not-working-on-asp-net-core-3-0-for-user-profile) and this [Updating default front-end design of Identity Login Page in .NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296041/updating-default-front-end-design-of-identity-login-page-in-net-core), but it did not help me.

UPDATE: This is from Chrome developer tools.  It looks like it is trying to pull the files from the Identity area instead of the root;

[image]

Comment: did you mean you missed the css file? to be honest, I can't understand your issue...

Comment: No.  The layout works perfect in all pages except the Identity pages (log in, manage profile, register).  The above first image is of the Identity pages.  It as if they are not getting a layout at all.  The second image is how the layout should be.  The home page has this.  When you go into an identity page, the layout is gone.  Once you login and get back to any other page besides an Identity page, the Layout comes back.  I have the correct layout in the Identity _ViewStart.cshtml as you can see above.  It is as if any Identity page is blocked from getting the layout.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And have you tried to add layout manually follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58804804/15581227)?

Comment: That is one of the ones I tried above.  I am going to try it again for good measure (you know, sometimes we leave out something) and I will report the results on here.

Comment: OK, I can say that the recommended solution does not work.  It is still as if the files are not there.  It has been a while since I did this.  Is there a way to give access to the Identity pages that I am missing?

Comment: `AddDefaultUI()` doesn't work as well? Is there any error messages for the symptom?

Comment: The only errors I see is when I try to go to the login page.  It looks like the pages are trying to pull from the Identity area instead of the root.  I will attach that image above.

Comment: It appears to me that it is looking under Identity to get the files it needs.  I am very confused as to why it is doing this.  I never had this issue on dotnet 3 or 5.

Comment: I don't have any other ideas then, but the description `pull from the Identity area instead of the root` may be a clue to troubleshoot the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the answer to this was to create a new project and move my files over.  I am not sure what was wrong, but now that I created a new project and move my files, everything works just rosie.